# What does 'critical account' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> a critical account of how the publications submitted address the
>   guiding research questions

I have encountered this requirement, but I could not find a definition for the phrase 'critical account'. I think it means 'justification'? or does this phrase have deeper meanings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One definition of "Critical account" is "[A response/analysis that analyses the validity of an author's claims.](https://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_critical_account)". In other words it is a comprehensive and carefully written book or article in which the author fully justifies each of his arguments and facts. All relevant questions are answered.